# CopyStreamException in JMeter FTP request

Tags: ftp, jmeter, ioexception

I have a server to which I am sending my files through FTP request Jmeter protocol.
I get this error in the results page and I don't know where the error resource is.

`org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught while copying.`

Edit: [image: Here] is the snapshot of my test screen

Comment: Can you please share your FTP test plan snapshot? Thanks!

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam the snapshot is added. Did I miss anything and my test is wrong?

Comment: are you able to manually upload? Does the credentials has valid access to upload? Please clarify.

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam The connection does not go to the credential step. I have checked that when the error is the login configuration the error returns that the user/pass is incorrect. But here it does not go beyond a simple syn and syn ack between the client and server and the client does not even ask for the FTP connection. Also, yes the credentials has valid access I have checked it.

Comment: Who is just downgrading me and why :| I have just asked a question!

Comment: I'm not sure what are you talking about. I tried in my system, I'm not able to replicate your issue :(

Comment: can you try opening jmeter behind proxy and let me know?

Answer (score 0):

- Double check whether local file exists and the path is correct
- Double check that remote path exists and your user has write permissions to that location
- Double check you are using `put (STOR)` method and appropriate `Use Binary Mode?` checkbox state

If you are still experience problems follow the next troubleshooting steps:

1. Try to upload the same file using "normal" FTP client like [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) or [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php)
2. Update your question with the screenshot, demonstrating FTP Request sampler configuration and eventually [FTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#FTP_Request_Defaults) and the full log file
3. Raise an issue to [JMeter issue tracker](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) (be ready to have answers mentioned in points 1 and 2)

Check out [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter) to learn more on the domain, examples and alternative options.